# Blade Component to create Menus or Lists

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.7

I was looking for a while a way to create a component but to create as many slots as needed dinamically.

For example, you want to repeat a menu list style in your project multiple times, the best option is to have a component, but what if i need custom html options each element, that makes it tricky.

Answer (score 0):

The best option so far i get is the following, hope someone finds it helpfull

In your view file:

```
 @component('components.radioList',['values'=>[1,2,3,4],'name'=>'myname'])
    @slot('html_0')
      mi html item 0
    @endslot
    @slot('html_1')
      mi html item 1
    @endslot
    @slot('html_2')
      mi html item 2
    @endslot
    @slot('html_3')
      mi html item 3
    @endslot
  @endcomponent
```

In your component blade:

```
<ul class="list-group">
    @foreach($values as $value)
        @isset(${"html_{$loop->index}"})
            <li class="list-group-item custom-control custom-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck_{{$loop->index}}" name="{{$name}}" value="{{$value}}">
                <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck_{{$loop->index}}">
                    {{ ${"html_{$loop->index}"} }} 
                </label>
            </li>
        @endisset
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

The only thing is that the values, and the amount of slots needs to match.

If you dont need extra values for each slot, you can create as a count:

```
 @component('components.radioList',['count'=>4,'name'=>'myname'])
```

And change the Foreach to a For

Cheers!